# Source script with user input

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, user-input

I have a script that is something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "User: "
read -e username
echo -n "Password: "
read -es password

export http_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"
export https_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"

$@

unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

It reads the user/pass, export the proxy, run the command I need the proxy then clean it.
It works. But I tried making this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "User: "
read -e username
echo -n "Password: "
read -es password

export http_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"
export https_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"
```

So I could `source proxyscript` (and be able to use the proxy for a whole session without needing to put user/pass everytime), it waits for input, but exports `http://:@localhost:40080`

---

So, what I'm doing wrong or how can I make it work?

(I know I can make it as args and use `$1`/`$2`, or something like that, but I would like to avoid having to have the password open in the history)

---

Edit/Solution:

Building on the answers, a small change was enough to make it compatible with both `bash` and `zsh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "User: "
read username
echo -n "Password: "
read -s password

export http_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"
export https_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"
```

Basically, just removed the `e` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get why it isn't working, it works fine for me:

```
$ source foo.sh
User: terdon
Password: ~ $   ## I entered the password here, you can add an echo to clear the line

$ echo "$http_proxy"
http://terdon:myPass@localhost:40080
$ echo "$https_proxy" 
http://terdon:myPass@localhost:40080
```

I would use `read -p` instead of the `echo`, and add an empty `echo` to clear the line, but apart from that, your approach should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "User: " -e username
read -p "Password: " -es password
echo ""

export http_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"
export https_proxy="http://$username:$password@localhost:40080"
```

You can now do `. foo.sh` (or `source foo.sh` since you're using bash) and it should work as expected.

Comment: you're right, it works!
but using the p flag I got an error, which led me to discover that the problem is my shell... i'm using zsh...

Comment: Ah, yes, you can't source a bash script that easily into a  zsh session.

Answer (score 1):

ZSH is not bash; the shells have incompatible `read` builtins. `bash`:

> -e     If the standard input is coming from a terminal, readline
> (see READLINE above) is used to obtain the  line.   Read-
> line  uses  the  current (or default, if line editing was
> not previously active) editing settings, but  uses  Read-
> line's default filename completion.

ZSH:

> -e
> -E     The input read is printed (echoed) to the  standard  out-
> put.  If the -e flag is used, no input is assigned to the
> parameters.

So `read -e` in `bash` is some readline thing and `read -e` in ZSH is to
only echo. If you want to `source` shell code using ZSH, the code
sourced must be written for ZSH.